# How do I write a Python class that is a node in a linked list while using type hinting

Tags: python

In Python 3.7, I have a dataclass that is a node in a linked list.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Node(object):
    right: Node
    left: Node
```

The problem is that I get an inspection error in Pycharm:

> Unresolved reference 'Node'

and this error when running

> NameError: name 'Node' is not defined

dataclass requires I declare the type, so how do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

[PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) solves this.

By adding the following import, the type hinting is resolved later on.

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Comment: I would just note that it's only true for python 3.7+

Comment: PEP 563 states "Just like in PEP 484 and PEP 526, it should be emphasized that Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention." 

but this in contrast to https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html, where you can see that dataclasses require type hinting to work.

So, it looks to me that is a case where the answer's import is mandatory

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044854/how-to-create-linked-lists-using-pydantic-so-auto-completion-doesnt-break - Adding the type hint of the same type in quotes.