# How to create linked lists using pydantic so auto-completion doesn't break

Tags: python, linked-list, pydantic

I am trying to create a linked list using pydantic.

The following code works, but I can't get auto-completion to work. As you can see from the attached screenshot, the property 'next' doesn't show auto-completion.

How do I preserve the auto-comp

**Update**: I am working on Pycharm Professional 2020.3 + Python 3.10.2 + pydantic 1.9.0

---

### Code

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.typing import ForwardRef

Node = ForwardRef('Node')


class Node(BaseModel):
    data: int
    next: Node = None


# Node.update_forward_refs()

def get_l1() -> Node:
    l1: Node = Node(data=1)
    l1.next = Node(data=2)
    l1.next.next = Node(data=3)

    return l1


l2: Node = get_l1()

print(l2)
print(l2.next)
print(l2.next.next)
```

---

### Output

```
data=1 next=Node(data=2, next=Node(data=3, next=None))
data=2 next=Node(data=3, next=None)
data=3 next=None
```

---

### Screenshot

[image: l2.next does not show auto-completion]

Comment: Please add the information of your IDE to the question. Auto-completion on your code works for me in VS Code `1.66.2` with the Python `v2022.4.1` and Pylance `v2022.4.3` extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Pycharm Professional 2020.3 + Python 3.10.2 + pydantic 1.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `ForwardRef`, use `typing.Optional` because you are assigning `None` to the `node` field and surround `Node` with quotes:

```python
# Node = ForwardRef('Node')  <- Do not use this


class Node(BaseModel):
    data: int
    next: Optional["Node"] = None # <- Use typing.Optional and quotes here
```

About `typing.Optional` from the [pydantic documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#standard-library-types):

> `typing.Optional`
>
> `Optional[x]` is simply short hand for `Union[x, None]`;

About the usage of quotes in a type hint of a forward reference according to [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.
>
> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature of some of the methods. For example, the following code (the start of a simple binary tree implementation) does not work:
>
> ```python
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> To address this, we write:
>
> ```python
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```

Comment: Thanks Hernan. This works like magic. Didn't know about this feature. Auto-Completion works great on Python 3.10 and Python 3.6.5.